# Get Table information using foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I want to get all rows in a table where the foreign key is a set value.

So I have the line underneath to get all the values in the table `Resultater`

```
var resultater = _context.Resultater.ToArray();
```

I want to limit the results to only those that match the foreign key. I would imagine it to be something like:

```
var foreignKey = 1;
var resultater = _context.Resultater.Where(ForeignKey == foreignKey).ToArray();
```

The model/table looks like this

```
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ForeignKey { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dato")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Form { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question and what issue you are facing?

Comment: In the table `Resultater` I have the column `ForeignKey` and I want all rows that match the `foreignKey`. The problem is that I don't know how to limit the result from `_context.Resultater.ToArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change the lambda query like this

```
var foreignKey = 1;
var resultater = _context.Resultater.Where(x=> x.ForeignKey == foreignKey).ToArray();
```